# Use VBA to toggle conditional formatting on and off

Tags: vba, excel

How do I use VBA to toggle conditional formatting on and off?

I have a range C3:AD46. I have two conditional formats.

[image]
[image]

I want to toggle the first format on/off using a macro. The second format can stay enabled all the time.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use `.FormatConditions.Delete` to remove the conditions and if you want to enable it again you can use `.FormatConditions.Add` method with the given range. [Reference](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=138066)

Comment: to toggle one conditional formatting on / off, use `=AND( some formula, toggleboolean)`, thus you can control on/off by adjusting the `toggleboolean`

Comment: The first example I gave doesn't use a formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first format I was able to piece together the following:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
   Dim rngMyRange As Range

   Set rngMyRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("tim-vgr_hgn").Range("C3:AO46")  'Set your range here

    If rngMyRange.FormatConditions.Count = 0 Then  'Set Conditional Formats
      With rngMyRange
            .FormatConditions.AddColorScale ColorScaleType:=3

            ' Format the first color as green
            .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Type = xlConditionValueNumber
            .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).Value = 0
            .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(1).FormatColor.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)

            ' Format the second color as yellow
            .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Type = xlConditionValueNumber
            .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).Value = 120
            .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(2).FormatColor.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)

            ' Format the third color as red
            .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Type = xlConditionValueNumber
            .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).Value = 7200
            .FormatConditions(1).ColorScaleCriteria(3).FormatColor.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

      End With

    Else    'Clear Conditional Formats

      rngMyRange.FormatConditions.Delete

    End If
End Sub
```

But, how do I recreate the second format?

[edit]

I will start a new question for the second format.

Answer (score 3):

One method you could use, rather than reproducing the conditional formats via VBA code, would be to use the "Stop If True" feature within the conditional formatting screen.

The idea is that your VBA code could change the value of a single cell and then a new conditional formatting rule would check the cell value. If true the conditional formatting would apply no new formatting changes, instead as the "Stop If True" chechbox would be selected the new rule would simply prevent excel from checking the rules below (i.e. the rule you want to be controlled by your VBA code). This effectively means the hidden cell value acts like a boolean 'switch' that controls whether the conditional format rules are run or not.